# Extracting the last action of last employee

Tags: java, string, file, stringtokenizer

```
        5023971 s   2016-05-22 21:34:48     
        5023971 s   2016-05-22 21:35:57     
        5023971 s   2016-05-22 21:36:35     
        5023971 s   2016-05-22 21:37:42     
        5023971 s   2016-05-22 21:39:41 3   sple
        5296256 d   2016-03-04 08:05:12     
        5296256 d   2016-03-04 08:05:13     
        5296256 d   2016-03-04 08:05:14 4   sup
        5324887 d   2016-05-06 10:22:22     
        5324887 d   2016-05-06 10:22:30 2   sup
        79159   r l 2016-03-13 16:33:59 1   roy
        1318887 g a 2016-03-15 11:59:09 2   gg
        1318887 g a 2016-03-21 13:26:13 1   gglrt
        4821757 y a 2016-05-24 19:46:39 8   hnd
```

Consider we have a list of employees that contains the employee id, name, time, a random number and an action performed by the employee. the name is either one or two tokens but the actions are always with one token. What we are interested to do is to extract the last action that an employee performs with his/her name.(for example: `s` and `sam`, `d` and `sup` etc.)
The code below does the job but it extracts the first action of each distinct employee. How to modify it to meet the requirement?

```
 static StringTokenizer a;
 public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
try { 
    Integer.parseInt(s); 
} catch(NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) { 
    return false; 
}
    return true;
 }

 static boolean first=true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(file);

    String line;
    String name="";
    String tempaction="";
    String action="";

    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

                  int  nameLenght=0;
                  String tempName="";
                  String temp2;
                  String temp3;
                    a=new StringTokenizer(line);

                  if(first){
                    while(a.hasMoreTokens()){
                        temp2=a.nextToken();
                        temp3=temp2.charAt(0)+"";
                        if((temp2).startsWith("2016") ) break;
                        if(!isInteger(temp3)){
                            nameLenght++;
                            tempName=tempName+" "+temp2;

                        }


                    }
                       if(nameLenght<3 && !name.equals(tempName)){

                            name=tempName;
                           System.out.println(name);
                          first=false;
                       }
                  }

                   action="";
                    if(!first){
                      while(a.hasMoreTokens() ){

                        temp2=a.nextToken();
                        temp3=temp2.charAt(0)+"";
                        if((temp2).startsWith("2016") ) break;
                        if(!isInteger(temp3)){
                            action=action+" "+temp2;

                        }                       

                    }

                      if(!tempAction.equals(action)){
                           tempAction=action; 
                           System.out.println(action);
                           first=true;
                          }

                      first=true;
                    }
                    }
    }
```

Comment: It's really hard to follow your logic when your variables have meaningless names like `temp`, `temp2`, `temp3`, `tempT` etc. Moreover, this is a fixed-length field format. It's not a good idea to process it with a string tokenizer. The logic will be much simpler if you grab the fields by their position in the line.

Comment: @RealSkeptic but the employees names arent fixed, they are longer than one in length. So I have to count the length fitst. if it was 1 or 2 then get the last action. something like this. And I made few changes for names of vars. temp 2 and temp 3 are those unimportat parts (IDs and date and time).

Comment: In the file that you gave then the employee name field is fixed - it's always 3 characters, though some of them may be spaces.

Comment: @RealSkeptic no, the first integer is ID, then there are either one or two letters as the name. (it is from left to right. last common on the right is the action.)

Comment: Look carefully. You can always take the three letters that follow the integer. They can be a letter and two spaces, or a letter, a space, and a letter. It's always three characters. Again, according to the file you posted here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic imagine fixed 3 letters, now what?

Comment: @RealSkeptic My code works well but I want the last line for each employee to be taken out (name and action) not the first one (as my current code does).

Comment: @RealSkeptic no it is sam,  Look at it again please.

Comment: @PatrickParker nono you mistook me. last action of each employee. not last action in the file. the date is sorted for each employee but because  cropped a part of the log, the date does not look sorted but you can see it is sorted for each employee.

Comment: Action "sple" for user "s" appears earlier in the file than action "sam" for user "s". Look at the timestamps. Whatever. I already adjusted my code to sort by timestamp so the position in the file is irrelevant.

Comment: @PatrickParker that was a mistake from me. I have removed it. for the whitespace, the problem is that the whitespaces are not fixed, sometimes there is white space between the id and name and sometimes not (same thing for other entities). but there is no whitespace before ids or after actions.

Comment: @user3049183 if you want to make one of the spaces optional, change it from `"\\s+"` to `"\\s*"`, but be warned that it creates additional assumptions. For example, the assumption that the user id will not begin or end with a number, and the assumption that the action will not begin with a number. That makes the code really fragile to have so many assumptions and it would be better to get the substring based on known positions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting the last action for each employee (using Java 8 Streams and Regular Expression matching)

```
private static final Pattern LINE_REGEX = Pattern.compile(
        "^\\s*" // space before user id
        + "[0-9]+" // user id
        + "\\s+" // space after user id
        + "(.*?[^\\s])" // user name (group 1)
        + "\\s+" // space after user name
        + "([0-9]+-.{14})" // timestamp (group 2)
        + "\\s+" //space after timestamp
        + "[0-9]*" // random int
        + "\\s+" //space after random int
        + "(.*[^\\s])" // user action (group 3)
        + "\\s*$" // space after user action
);
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("emplog.txt"))) {
        Map<String,String> result = stream.map(LINE_REGEX::matcher)
            // filter out any lines without an Action
            .filter(Matcher::matches)
            // group by User
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((Matcher m) -> m.group(1),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    // compare Timestamp (min for earliest, max for latest)
                    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing((Matcher m) -> m.group(2))),
                    // extract Action
                    (Optional<Matcher> m) -> m.get().group(3))));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> {s=sple, d=sup, g a=gglrt, y a=hnd, r l=roy}

(If any users have no actions, they will not be listed.)

Comment: filter(Matcher::matches) gets the invalid reference for calling non-static method within a static method.

Comment: I dont know why it is not working on the actual log. Maybe because in the actual log the names are complete? like David instead of d? or there is some other explanation?

Comment: Oh I found it out why it is not working. in the real log, there are some more white spaces between each columns. Can you tell me how to modify your code to ignore these white spaces?

Comment: @user3049183 I have added some comments and modifications to the regexp. Try it again now. And don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept the correct answer.

Comment: Also, since you can't provide me the exact whitespace structure of the file, I had to rely on some assumptions. For example, an assumption that Action cannot begin with an integer-followed-by-whitespace (that will match the random int portion).

Comment: I have changed your regex a little bit. (removed the part for whitespace before id and after actions). but since not all the time whitespaces are like this, can you tell me how to make the whitespaces optional? because even though it gives some correct results, but it returns few strange results for at the beginning. (results included with number 20)

Comment: @user3049183 your problem description is too vague. try uploading the following things into a pastebin and sharing the link (or else post a new question with these details): 1) an actual line or two of input that causes a problem 2) the actual regexp or code you are using 3) the actual output you are seeing 4) the desired output.